# Horizontal swiping for wide tables with too many columns in mobile

Tags: mobile, tables

working on a size chart for a apparel e-commerce app. there are some extreme cases were some products seem to have so many sizes. the layout of the table isn't changeable. so i think the best solution would be introducing a horizontal scroll. which of these options to you think is most intuitive to the user
[image]

Comment: Of course, you'll want to keep the left column sticky so we can see those labels as we scroll to our own sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would go for something like option 3 or 4.**  Both of them are pretty clear.  Options 1 or 2, I think, have a greater risk of being misunderstood.

**Option 1 looks like an indicator for multiple pages,** not scrolling the table.  (I'm assuming that the screen will have more than just the table visible, in which case these dots might make the user expect the entire page will change when they swipe).

**Option 2 looks like a progress bar**.  Also, even if identified as a scroll bar, it might not be clear that it applies to the table, rather than something else (such as content below it).

Answer (score -1):

If we're talk about UX, then why do you even need a size chart? Buyer doesn't care about all these letters and numbers, he's looking only for his own size. I'd ask him his sizes (I mean the numbers, 'cause the letters sometimes mismatch with sizes) and offer only apparel with that size.